# Setting Initial in a ModelFormset

Tags: django

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values) providing initial values for fields that are bound to a model is not possible.

In my model form though I have created an additional unbound field:

```
class DealCForm(ModelForm):
    attach_deal_conversation  = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False)
```

Hence I would like to set this value if certain conditions are met.

**View:**

```
deal_formset = modelformset_factory(Deal, form=DealCForm, extra=0)

if (request.POST)
        pass
else:                 
        opendeal_formset = deal_formset(queryset=formset_query)
variables = RequestContext(request, {'opendeal_formset' : opendeal_formset)
return render_to_response('conversation.html', variables)
```

In the view, just before sending it to the template, I have set the value directly, however it doesn't work:

```
for dfm in deal_formset:
            for odfm in opendeal_formset:
                if dfm.pk == odfm.pk:
                    odfm.attach_deal_conversation = True;
```

But it doesn't work. ANy idea how to set the initial value for an unbound field?

Many Thanks

Comment: That's not what the documentation says. It says that initial values don't apply to the forms for *pre-existing* instances; they do apply to "extra" forms, or those that haven't been saved yet. This is ideal, because if it's an existing instance, you want its saved data to show up initially, not your default initial data.

Comment: Well, I dont have any extra form. But could I set the initial value for the one unbound field ? I think I need to pass it as Array with a tuple inside...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This runs for me:

```
for form in opendeal_formset:
    form.fields['attach_deal_conversation'].initial=True
```